# strange Jquery behavior: after clicking close button on pop-up, another jquery plugin stops working

Tags: jquery, debugging

Could you please hemp me get to the bottom of this problem? I don't have enough experience or knowledge.

Visit: http://dev.holiday.ge/xhtml/login-signup.html

Click "Add an event", pop-up will appear, check out drop downs everything works.
Close pop-up
Click again "Add an event", check the dropdowns - they stopped working.

How can I fix this? or why does this happen?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First step, open up the console in Chrome/Safari or Firebug/Firefox.

Step two, do the actions you describe.

Step 3, see the error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'cached_width' of undefined`

Step 4, notice that when you 'close' the dropdown, you're actually completely removing it from the DOM. Thus, loosing all the action listeners bound to the dropdowns.

Step 5, add the `.dropp()` calls to happen only when you open the thing (or just stop removing it when it's closed)

Step 6, thank me for seeing your rookie mistake ;)